# Swift SDWebImage never executes completion

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I must be doing sth silly, but `SDWebImage` never executes the completion handler in the following:

```
episodeImageView?.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: { [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, url) in
    print("Looped!") // NEVER!
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard  let image = self?.episodeImageView?.image else { return }
        self!.episodeView.animate(image, imageAnimationDuration: 10, initialDelay: 0, shouldLoop: true)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
episodeImageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
    //Your Code
}
```

Comment: Sorry! That makes no difference. And, it shouldn't. Both syntaxes are allowed.

Comment: you mean completion block is not executing?